# Why does videos not resume from last point played? Fedora

Tags: video, fedora, gnome

Basically, why does videos (Fedora's default gnome application for playing video files) not resume from the last point played when I close and re-open it? And is there a way to make it do so? I looked in gnome's tweaks app, and searched online, but couldn't come up with anything.

Edit: And why can't I play two videos at the same time? Is there a way to do so? (In separate windows)

Comment: You may have more a better time installing a few other video players and seeing what meets your needs.

Comment: Okay, so there's no solution then?

Comment: Personally, I don't know.  Someone might know and chime in.  SuperUser's sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place to search.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll accept this as the answer, but I'll leave the question open in case somebody can answer.